# Remove Custom HTML Posts Using Regex

Tags: regex

I want to delete the custom HTML that is in all posts. It is impossible for me to edit one post at a time because there have been many posts that I have published.

I want to delete it using Regex via **Search Regex** plugin.

I am confused about the part that I want to delete. I want to delete everything from the `<!-- wp:html -->` tag to `<!-- /wp:html -->`. How to do it?

Comment: Since you're using a specific plugin, please refer to their documentation and support channels. It may vary depending on the plugin itself. If you're open to custom-code solutions you may still get answers here, or might also want to try asking on StackOverflow since that would be more of a MySQL question than a WP-specific one.

Comment: This can be rephrased simpler as _how do I remove all the custom HTML blocks in my posts automattically?_ Note that by choosing Regex to do this you make this problem 50x harder to solve. You can't parse HTML with regex unless it's a set of specific circumstances due to how HTML markup is structured